# InfluxDB does not store metrics when setting non default retention policy

Tags: influxdb

I'm using open source version of InfluxDB on Windows with default settings. I tried 1.6.4 and 1.7.1.
When I specify any retention policy then default, the data is not stored.

For test purposes I've created two identical retention policies - default and non_default:

```
show retention policies
name        duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----        -------- ------------------ -------- -------
default     168h0m0s 24h0m0s            1        true
non_default 168h0m0s 24h0m0s            1        false
```

When I'm posting data with the non_default retention policy nothing happens. The server returns a success but there is no data in metrics.

```
$ curl -i -XPOST " http://influx1:8086/write?db=test&amp;rp=non_default" --data-binary 'TestViaHttp,mytag=a myfield=90'
```

When I'm posting data with default retention policy it is inserted successfully.

```
$ curl -i -XPOST " http://influx1:8086/write?db=test&amp;rp=default" --data-binary 'TestViaHttp,mytag=a myfield=90'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out, that you should specify retention policy in select statement.

`SELECT * FROM "non_default"."TestViaHttp"`

Looks like retention policies are similar to schemas in MS SQL.

Comment: Here's the thing, a mistake that virtually every Influx nub do: thinking of it in good 'ol SQL terms (just because it looks familiar). Don't. Just don't. You'd avoid a lot of frustrations as you go. And no, retention policies aren't very much like schemas.